# Restore AppData overwritten files

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery, volume-shadow-copy, overwrite, appdata

History of issue: I was trying to restore my deleted tab history of Mozilla Firefox browser, which I didn't synchronize with my account, and I have made a LOT of mistakes. I tried to **restore previous versions** of files via **Shadow Copies** with *ShadowExplorer*. My first mistake was that *I didn't create backup of that folder before overwritting it* with ShadowExplorer. Second, I tried to restore files with **System Restore**, however, I didn't knew much and ended up rebooting my pc, and, unfortunatelly, it did nothing (Which I know now that it only restores registers for some reason).

Is there any possible way of restoring those files? I tried turning off **TRIM** for ***C:*** drive, using recovering software, like **Disk Drill** or **Stellar Data Recovery**, but I can't retrieve my files back with them. I even tried viewing shadow copies again with **Recuva** and other software, but they aren't working, because data there is strangely corrupted.

I didn't have file history turned on, because windows 8 has it *turned off* by default, nor any backups. I know, that is stupid.

Please, if you have any idea how to fix this, please, help me. I am looking for anything. I am begging for any possibility.

Edit: I know it doesn't change much, but I realised that I exported copied data from shadow copy directly to the same folder where it was stored. As an example: '/AppData/Local' from shadow copy to the same original folder '/AppData/Local'. Could it be the reason why data was corrupted?

Comment: You keep on butchering your computer, doing stuff that you don't understand. I suggest to undo everything that you did and accept the fact that without backup your files are lost. You could have a look in the Recycle Bin, but the chances are slim.

Comment: "I tried turning off TRIM" - As rule of thumb Windows sends TRIM commands immediately, in which case turn off TRIM after the fact has zero effect. If you downloaded file recovery tools to that same drive, whatever chance you had has further diminished. Even just continue running the OS has. Long story short, you're likely out of luck.

Comment: If only I came here for advice immediately. I cannot believe what have I done. And because of my stupidity and carelessness, I installed Disk Drill on C drive, expecting it to give me option to do so, but it the settings were hidden.

Comment: Based on what you describe I wouldn't expect being able to restore your files.

Comment: In the future, perform full disk imaging periodically. It's the *only* reliable way to get back to a previous state.

Comment: I know that already. I wish I could do something, or didn't do anything at all. I always did backups when I manipulate files like that. I just forgot and that is just horrible

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck, you went too far, sorry.

Based on the information you have given you've likely irrevocably lost the data you want.

IF there is significant monetary value you should take your computer to a forensic data recovery team, where you will likely be charged significant amounts of money for a slim chance some of the data may be recovered.

Comment: I just realised that I copied files from shadow copy and pasted them into the same folder, which could be the issue of corruption. It also explains why all of them are the same as current corrupted version.